MS Word - Keep AutoCorrect options unvaried through updates
I have most AutoCorrect options turned off in Microsoft Word. I intend the options available through: File -> Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options... , and then going through the various tabs.
However, at least every 2-3 months some update will turn the options back on.
Is there any way to keep these options 'locked down' during updates?
I'm using Word 365 with a business account, if it matters.

You can record a VBA macro setting the options the way you want them, and then run that macro each time Microsoft has messed them up again...

@Paul good idea, but i'd like to avoid the issue altogether, if possible.

See  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-get-my-changes-to-words-autocorrect-to/4e91e304-e4cf-494d-bfc4-a4f690b47bed.

@CharlesKenyon OK, so it's effectively a bug. I'll consider to make a macro until it's fixed. Thank you.
